# ¿Alguien sabe cómo mostrar datos específicos de un JSON de Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo un JSON del que sólo quiero coger los datos de área, pero no se cómo hacerlo ya que todos los datos se identifican con la etiqueta v.

[Enlace al json](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9P6ESB17Y-Jc053di12dzFuWE0/view?usp=sharing)

El código de abajo es el que utilizo para guardar el JSON (leído previamente de una URL) en un array y lo recorro para que sólo me muestre los datos de las filas.

```
var data = httpRequest.responseText;
arrayDatos = data.split('{"c":');

for(var i = 1 ; i < arrayDatos.length; i++)
{
     document.getElementById("body").innerHTML +=  arrayDatos[i] + '<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás procesando el JSON como si fuese una cadena cuando podrías (y deberías) parsearlo y utilizarlo como un objeto, entonces sería mucho más fácil trabajar con los datos contenidos en el mismo.

Por ejemplo, esta es una versión simplificada de lo que tienes:

```
{
  "version":"0.6",
  "reqId":"0",
  "status":"ok",
  "sig":"1326357147",
  "table":{
    "cols":[
      {
        "id":"A",
        "label":"Ref",
        "type":"number",
        "pattern":"General"
      },
      {
        "id":"B",
        "label":"Ãrea",
        "type":"string"
      },
      {
        "id":"C",
        "label":"Curso",
        "type":"string"
      }
    ],
    "rows":[
      {
        "c":[
          {
            "v":1.0,
            "f":"1"
          },
          {
            "v":"DiseÃ±o"
          },
          {
            "v":"Flash CS4 bÃ¡sico"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "c":[
          {
            "v":2.0,
            "f":"2"
          },
          {
            "v":"DiseÃ±o"
          },
          {
            "v":"Freehand MX "
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

En lugar de leerlo como una cadena de texto, debes procesarlo como JSON usando [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/parse). Y a partir de ahi todo va a ser muy sencillo porque sabes que la segunda columna es el área:

```
// parsea la cadena como JSON
var datos = JSON.parse( variable_que_contiene_el_json_como_cadena );

// sabes que las filas están en datos.table.rows, así que atraviesa ese array
for (var x = 0; x < datos.table.rows.length; x++) {

    // mostrando para cada fila, el valor (v) de la segunda columna (c[1])
    console.log(datos.table.rows[x].c[1].v);
}
```